# azkaban single web server (multiple executor mode) executor id change issue

Tags: azkaban

I have got an azkaban single web server (multiple executor mode).I have been able to force execute the crons on required servers.But whenever there is a executor server restart the executor table gets updated with a new executor id.How to fix it since with such behaviour i will have to reschedule jobs with new executor id

Comment: Do you still keep executor.port property in web server config ?